# What is the use of assert_predicate in MiniTest?

Tags: ruby, minitest

I have a problem understanding the usefulness of `assert_predicate` in MiniTest. How is it different from `assert_equal?` When would one want to use this assertion? I have came across it many times but did not really get its exact meaning.

Comment: `assert_equal` would result in a super-useless message on failure, something along the lines of "expected true to equal true, but got false instead".

Comment: The only use is a better message on the assertion failing. Which is really the only use of all the extra `assert_*` methods -- otherwise really all you need is the single `assert` method. It's failure messages just aren't too useful.

Answer (score 17):

`assert_equal` checks to see whether the expected and actual values are equal:

```
assert_equal "Bender", robot.name
```

`assert_predicate` calls the named method on your target object and passes if the result is truthy:

```
assert_predicate robot, :bender?
```

You could just as easily write this test as:

```
assert robot.bender?
```

But `assert_predicate` can be a little more expressive in some situations and can be a little nicer when checking multiple predicate conditions:

```
roles = %i(admin? publisher? operator?)
roles.each {|role| assert_predicate user, role }
```

Comment: It also provides a better error message in case of failures.

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation for the method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/seattlerb/minitest/Minitest/Assertions:assert_predicate) itself may answer your question:

> For testing with predicates. Eg:
>
> `assert_predicate str, :empty?`
>
> This is really meant for specs and is front-ended by assert_operator:
>
> `str.must_be :empty?`

That suggests that the reason is to support `.must_be` calls rather than providing any specific benefit over `assert_equal` or `assert`.